# SQL OLE DB Error with ColdFusion while uploading an excel file

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 with Coldfusion. I am trying to upload an excel file using a stored proc using linked servers. I am getting the following error.

> [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]OLE DB provider
>   'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' cannot be used for distributed queries
>   because the provider is configured to run in single-threaded apartment
>   mode.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for just posting a link, but Pinal Dave discusses a (partial) solution to this issue [in this post](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/11/03/sql-server-fix-error-ms-jet-oledb-4-0-cannot-be-used-for-distributed-queries-because-the-provider-is-used-to-run-in-apartment-mode/).

Mitch Stokely posted a further solution [in this comment](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/11/03/sql-server-fix-error-ms-jet-oledb-4-0-cannot-be-used-for-distributed-queries-because-the-provider-is-used-to-run-in-apartment-mode/#comment-138673).

From Mitch's solution:

1. On 64-bit servers and boxes, you need to first UNINSTALL all 32-bit Microsoft Office applications and instances (Access 2007 install, Office 10 32-bit, etc.). If you dont, you cannot install the new 64-bit Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable components. Yes, its a headache but the only way I found to install the new replacements for the JET engine components that need to run on 64-bit machines.
2. Download and install the new component from Microsoft
3. { Run the SQL he provides }
4. Make sure you're using the new JET parameters as needed.
5. Re-install 64-bit MS-Office